# POSTing data into Craft

Tags: routing, post

I have a site set up that uses Craft as a CMS only, not used to display templates, as this is handled by React JS separately.

My site is set up so that Craft responds on `/api`.

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to POST data into a section!

I have a route set up, so my routes file is like:

```
return array(
    'post-message' => array(
        'action' => 'entries/saveEntry',
        'sectionId' => 13,
    ),
);
```

I am trying to test this using Rested app, posting a couple of fields into my section, but it doesn't do anything.

Rested is pointing to `/api/post-message` using a POST request.

I can't find any documentation that tutors a developer on how to post data into a section, so I'm completely stuck here.

Comment: Currently researching the best approach to use Craft as a headless CMS. May I ask how your set up of front- and backend looks like? Do you run the React frontend in a different environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to get into plugin controllers and actions you can replicate this format here: https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/entry-form

And trick Craft into believing your data comes from an entry form.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I have tried this to no avail, but I think there may have been a server POST issue that I have to investigate tomorrow. I'll get back to you...